# [TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativePdfLib.default.getDocumentsDirectory')]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to create pdf in my application using [react-native-pdf-lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pdf-lib) but I face this error

[TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativePdfLib.default.getDocumentsDirectory')]

my code

```
 const page1 = PDFPage.create()
.setMediaBox(200, 200)
.drawText('You can add text and rectangles to the PDF!', {
  x: 5,
  y: 235,
  color: '#007386',
})
.drawRectangle({
  x: 25,
  y: 25,
  width: 150,
  height: 150,
  color: '#FF99CC',
})
.drawRectangle({
  x: 75,
  y: 75,
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  color: '#99FFCC',
});
const handleCreatePdf = async () => {
try {
  const docsDir = await PDFLib.getDocumentsDirectory();
  const pdfPath = `${docsDir}/ex.pdf`;
  PDFDocument.create(pdfPath)
    .addPages(page1)
    .write() // Returns a promise that resolves with the PDF's path
    .then(path => {
      console.log('PDF created at: ' + path);
      // Do stuff with your shiny new PDF!
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

};

Any clue what's the problem, or maybe solution ?

Comment: Could you give a bit more information about the error showing? Like the line or other information that is being logged? I believe this would make it easier to find out where the error occurred.

Comment: @AndréGuimarãesAragon I get only error in the console from the catch which is ` LOG  [TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativePdfLib.default.getDocumentsDirectory')]` that's the only error I have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched to this library... seems to be more up to date and easier to use
https://github.com/Anyline/react-native-image-to-pdf

```
import RNImageToPdf from 'react-native-image-to-pdf';

const myAsyncPDFFunction = async () => {
    try {
        const options = {
            imagePaths: imagePaths: ['/path/to/image1.png','/path/to/image2.png'],
            name: name: 'PDFName',
            maxSize: { // optional maximum image dimension - larger images will be resized
                width: 900,
                height: Math.round(deviceHeight() / deviceWidth() * 900),
            },
            quality: .7, // optional compression paramter
        };
        const pdf = await RNImageToPdf.createPDFbyImages(options);
        
        console.log(pdf.filePath);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: could I merge images and pdfs and create a new pdf out of it?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a problem with the PDFLib object.

Is it imported correctly like this ?

```
import PDFLib, { PDFDocument, PDFPage } from 'react-native-pdf-lib';
```